# Ext JS - How to get name of application from within ViewModel?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

My Dr. Evil application has `name` defined as `DrEvil`:

```
Ext.define('DrEvil.Application', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',

    name: 'DrEvil',

    stores: [
        // TODO: add global / shared stores here
    ],

    launch: function () {
        // TODO - Launch the application
    }
});
```

In my view model, is there a way to retrieve this name? I was hoping something like `Ext.app.name` would pull it up but it comes up empty. I've been iterating through properties of `Ext`, `Ext.app` etc. and can't seem to find it.

This is probably something so trivial that it's looking me right in the face, but I did google N variations of *ExtJS get name of application within view model* with nothing relevant coming up.

I'm trying to convince the company to purchase the Eclipse plugin for ExtJS! Could probably answer this question in a second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually not obvious at all if you assume no knowledge of the application.

This is generic code which will do what you want:

`var name = Ext.app.Application.instance.getName();`

Or in recent versions of ExtJS:

`var name = Ext.getApplication().getName();`

Answer (score 2):

You are looking to get the application namespace.

```
DrEvil.app.getApplication().getName()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ext 4+ and create your application using the `Ext.application` syntax like so, there will be a reference to your application in the global namespace:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'DrEvil',
    launch: function() {
        // do some stuff
    }
});
```

http://docs.extjs.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.app.Application

At this point, `DrEvil` should be defined in the global scope. Now, you should be able to reference the application name as a string via `DrEvil.getApplication().name`, though that might be a bit redundant for what you're looking to do.

Hope this helps.